# Multiprocessing with Queue.queue in Python for numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I am reading a video using OpenCV with multithreading and using `queue.queue` to store the frames sequentially.

Further, I am trying to make use of multiprocessing for parallel processing of frames from the queue, to further speed up the execution time.

But I don't know how to efficiently pass the frames from the queue to multiple processes.

I tried `multiprocessing.queue` but its too slow.

Here is my current code for the multiprocessing part:

```
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    while q.not_empty():       
        frame = q.get()
        futures = executor.submit(func, frame)
```

This works, but it is slow.

How do I code the multiprocessing part with queue?

Using Windows OS, so can't use `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

Placing an array onto a `multiprocessing.Queue` creates a copy of the array, and allocating new memory is prohibitively slow. To avoid this, you can allocate a buffer in shared memory using [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

```py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

import numpy as np


frame_shape = (720, 1280, 3)
frame_dtype = np.uint8

buffer_size = np.prod(frame_shape) * np.dtype(frame_dtype).itemsize
buffer_name = "frame"

shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=buffer_size, name=buffer_name)

frame = np.ndarray(shape=frame_shape, dtype=frame_dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
```

In another process:

```py
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

import numpy as np


frame_shape = (720, 1280, 3)
frame_dtype = np.uint8

buffer_size = np.prod(frame_shape) * np.dtype(frame_dtype).itemsize
buffer_name = "frame"

shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(size=buffer_size, name=buffer_name)

frame = np.ndarray(shape=frame_shape, dtype=frame_dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
frame[:, :, :] = np.tile(np.arange(3), reps=(*frame_shape[:2], 1))
```

Back in the original process, the change is reflected:

```py
frame
```

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        ...,
```

When it is time to clean up, in the second process:

```py
shm.close()
```

And in the original process:

```py
shm.close()
shm.unlink()
```

If you do not unlink the `SharedMemory` object and you try to create another object with the same name (even after the process that instantiated it finishes executing), creation will fail until you do unlink it.

If you do not maintain a reference to the `SharedMemory` object, it can end up being garbage collected before you are done, so make sure to store it in a variable like we did above or a list, etc.

Be aware that you are going to need to synchronize access to the buffer with some kind of mutex like a [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) or a [`multiprocessing.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore).

Comment: can you tell me what this line is doing: frame[:, :, :] = np.tile(np.arange(3), reps=(*frame_shape[:2], 1))

Comment: Just copying some data in. The right-hand side is not important. `[:, :, :]` just means select the entirety of each of the first 3 dimensions of the array. In your code you would just replace the right-hand side with the image array you are wanting to copy over.

Comment: Ok, tell me if I am wrong. So for each frame I would need to allot a buffer in shared_mem and give it a unique name with a unique variable referenced to it, maybe with using  globals()[f"shm{i}"] , where 'i' iterates for every frame. This will create 'n' number of memory buffers which I could access from Multiple Processes using the names of the shared_mem. The names could be stored in Multiprocessing.Queue. What do you think, is the approach correct?

Comment: No creating one for each frame in the video defeats the purpose. You need to copy a frame into the shared memory array, read it, then copy the next one in to the same array, read it... until the video is done. You are using it in place of the queue.